# Specifying the Folderpath of S3 as working directory to terraform

Tags: python, amazon-s3, terraform

In a usual scenario we run terraform init in a directory where terraform gets initialized.

In python the commands can be run using subprocess.

How do we do that in lambda+Amazon S3.

How do I specify the directory path of S3 for terraform to initialize?

Answer (score 0):

Using a lambda to create AWS resource is not a good choice. If creating your stack take more than 15 minutes, the lambda will stop. It isn't designed to last more. And you have to download everytime the terraform binary by your lambda, which bring more complexity I think.

You should run terraform a CI/CD server for example.

Anyway, for your issue, it is written in the documentation. To be more helpful, this is I put in every project I'm managing:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket               = "mybucket"
    key                  = "path/stack.tfstate"
    region               = "eu-west-1"
    encrypt              = true
    workspace_key_prefix = ""
  }
}
```

And if you are coding in Python, I suggest you to use python-terraform.